# On clicking a button, show checklist on selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in Javascript and JQuery.

For Example: When I select Dragon and then click a button, the page will reload, and the selected option (Dragon) will show checklist (fontawesome) beside the text (Dragon).

Sorry for my bad English.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="example">Pet</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="example">
          <option>-Select Pet-</option>
          <option>Eagle</option>
          <option>Dragon</option>
          <option>Lion</option>
       </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted to show the checklist?

Comment: @DacreDenny I want the selected option have a mark (like checklist from fontawesome or anything)

Comment: is it okay when the page not load?

Comment: @codeformoney Is it hard when the page must reload ?

Comment: it depend when the page reload all data will reset. when you wnat to reload you need to store the data to your local storage

Comment: @codeformoney So, what should i do ?

Comment: @Tom-Cat check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<label for="example">Pet</label>
<select class="form-control" id="slct-pet">
  <option>-Select Pet-</option>
  <option id="eagle" value="eagle">Eagle</option>
  <option id="dragon" value="dragon">Dragon</option>
  <option id="lion" value="lion">Lion</option>
</select>
<button id="select">OK</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(() => {
    $('#slct-pet').on('change', function() {
      let selected = $(this).val();
      $('#select').on('click', () => {
        $('#'+selected).prepend('<p>CHECKED</p>')
      }) 
    })
  })
</script>
```